# Using Python to Read and Print Out a PCAP

Tags: python-3.x, pcap

This is for a school assignment
Relatively new to Python, and need some help. I'm required to read a PCAP file, and print out the source and destination IP's to a new file. I'm not allowed to use regex, I can't read the whole file at once, and I must use loops, functions (must accept one parameter and return a value), splits, and lists and IPs are in IPv4 format.

Are classes too complex for this problem?
EDIT: Where I am so far is below: The search performed below is pulling the wrong IPs. I was advised to search by find the 
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol

and then print the IPs from the line underneath it. I'm working on how to filter based on XXX.XXX.XXX format and will let you know how it goes :)

```
def pcapreader():

#open the file and print each line using readlines to a variable
#must replace file path with your present file location


    with open (r"filepath", "r") as f:
        f1=f.readlines()
        for x in f1:
            if "Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:" in x:
                ips = x.split("Src: ")[1].split(",")
                src = ips[0]
                dst = ips[1].split("Dst: ")[1]
                print("Src: {}\nDst:{}".format(src, dst))

    f.close()

def main ():

        pcapreader()


main()
```

I've attached a sample of the PCAP I need to read as well.[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: UPDATE: Trying to think my way through using the filter option for each line that's printed as a string, unsure how to though

Comment: is the attached image contains the file lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the lines you read will contain `Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:` then the source followed by the destination.

So, for that line you can do the following:

```
>>> ips = "Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.180, Dst: 239.255.255.250"
>>> ips = ip.split("Src: ")[1].split(",")
>>> ips
['192.168.1.180', ' Dst: 239.255.255.250']
>>> src = ips[0]
>>> dst = ips[1].split("Dst: ")[1]
>>> src
'192.168.1.180'
>>> dst
'239.255.255.250'
```

That line is named `ips` in the example, then source and destination extracted from it.

EDIT:

You can apply it in your code like this:

```
with open (r"filepath", "r") as f:
    f1=f.readlines()
    for x in f1:
      if "Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:" in x:
        ips = x.split("Src: ")[1].split(",")
        src = ips[0]
        dst = ips[1].split("Dst: ")[1]
        print("Src: {}\nDst:{}".format(src, dst))
        break
```

Hope this will help you.

**ADD**:
For the last edit, if you want the data from the line below the `Time Source ...` you can do the following:

```
with open (r"filepath", "r") as f:
    f1=f.readlines()
    flag = False
    for x in f1:
      if "No.\tTime\tSource" in x:
        flag = True
        continue

      if flag:# This will be executed just at the line after No.\tTime\tSource...
        src = x.split("\t")[3]
        dst = x.split("\t")[4]
        print("Src: {}\nDst: {}".format(src, dst))
        flag = False
```

Note: I assumed that between each string will be \t, if it doesn't worked then you have maybe to add some spaces or do something like this

Another note: while you are using `with` statement to open the file, you don't need to try to close that file, it will be closed automatically. You can see [this article](https://lerner.co.il/2015/01/18/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/) for more information

Comment: Thanks Kasper, I'll give it a shot! That would be within the first function?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you should check if the string `Internet Protocol Version 4` is in `x` variable which is the line.

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit, seeing it in the code helped tremendously! I'll give it a try :)

Comment: That worked really well! I was able to retrieve just the src and dst IPs as output, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're so welcome!
If it worked well, please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: so it appears that filtering off of Internet Protocol Version 4 is not providing me with my necessary results. The recommendation from my Professor is to search via the No. Time Destination Source line and then print the IPs in the 3rd and 4th element in the line below (hopefully that makes sense lol)

Comment: It does not, I'm not getting any output. I believe that there is more than \t between the fields. I counted 16 spaces between the fields
Also, thanks for the advice on the file closing. I like to include this as best practice and as a safety measure. Thank you though :)

Comment: Try to print `x` in that if statement to see how exactly the line will look like. If you're sure about the 16 spaces, you can use them as the splitter instead of \t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213717/discussion-between-samuel-fox-and-kasper).

Comment: @SamuelFox If this answer has answered your question, please mark it as such.